# How to insert an object in an ArrayList at a specific position

Tags: java, arraylist

Suppose I have an ArrayList of objects of size n. Now I want to insert an another object at specific position, let's say at index position k (is greater than 0 and less than n) and I want other objects at and after index position k to shift one index position ahead. So is there any way to do this directly in Java. Actually i want to keep the list sorted while adding new object.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

To **insert** value into ArrayList at particular index, use:

```
public void add(int index, E element)
```

This method will shift the subsequent elements of the list. but you    can not guarantee the List will remain sorted as the new Object you insert may sit on the wrong position according to the sorting order.

---

To **replace** the element at the specified position, use:

```
public E set(int index, E element)
```

This method replaces the element at the specified position in the
list with the specified element, and returns the element previously
at the specified position.

Comment: but i think it will replace the object at that index position

Comment: @Harsh there is nothing to think about actually - the docs are quite specific on what this method does http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int, E)

Comment: @Harsh to replace you can use set(int index, Object Obj)

Comment: what is the problem with sorting?  "the new object you insert may sit on the wrong position according to the sorting order"  so if i walk the arraylist from 0 until i find the right place to insert, then stick it in and the right side of the list shifts one to the right...why is order disrupted? ps java drools ruby rules

Comment: Note that `add()` is optional, meaning not all Java implementations of `ArrayList` nor `List` objects in general will necessarily support this method.

Answer (score 79):

Here is the simple arraylist example for insertion at specific index

```
ArrayList<Integer> str=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    str.add(0);
    str.add(1);
    str.add(2);
    str.add(3); 
    //Result = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    str.add(1, 11);
    str.add(2, 12);
    //Result = [0, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I prefer this answer, because it shows the results of the call(s).

Answer (score 2):

Note that when you insert into a List at a position, you are really inserting at a ***dynamic position*** within the List's current elements. See here:

http://tpcg.io/0KmArS

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      // create an empty array list with an initial capacity
      ArrayList<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);

      // use add() method to add elements in the list
      arrlist.add(15, 15);
      arrlist.add(22, 22);
      arrlist.add(30, 30);
      arrlist.add(40, 40);

      // adding element 25 at third position
      arrlist.add(2, 25);

      // let us print all the elements available in list
      for (Integer number : arrlist) {
         System.out.println("Number = " + number);
      }  
   }
}
```

> **$javac com/tutorialspoint/ArrayListDemo.java**
>
> **$java -Xmx128M -Xms16M com/tutorialspoint/ArrayListDemo**
>
> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 15, Size: 0
>     at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(ArrayList.java:661)
>     at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:473)
>     at com.tutorialspoint.ArrayListDemo.main(ArrayListDemo.java:12)
> ```

Comment: Source changed from: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_add_index.htm

Answer (score 2):

***From Oracle Official Documentation***

**This method Appends the specified element to the end of this list.**

```
add(E e) //append element to the end of the arraylist.
```

**This method Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.**

```
void add(int index, E element) //inserts element at the given position in the array list.
```

**This method Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element.**

```
set(int index, E element) //Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element.
```

Comment: From official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the way to do it on your specific question is `arrayList.add(1,"INSERTED ELEMENT");` where 1 is the position

Answer (score 0):

You must handle ArrayIndexOutOfBounds by yourself when adding to a certain position.

For convenience, you may use this extension function in Kotlin

```
/**
 * Adds an [element] to index [index] or to the end of the List in case [index] is out of bounds
 */
fun <T> MutableList<T>.insert(index: Int, element: T) {
    if (index <= size) {
        add(index, element)
    } else {
        add(element)
    }
}
```