# How can i add elements to the middle of pre existing 2D Arrays in java?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I have an array list declared as such:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>;
```

I have filled the inner array list with Strings that i parsed out of a text file. I will later add all of the array lists to a database.

After i first parse through and add data to the inner array list, i then want to go in and add additional data that can't be found in the files that i am parsing.

Here is the code i have tried but it is not working:

```
void SpecialOperations(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data) {
        for(ArrayList<String> sub: data){
            String ip = sub.get(0);
            //System.out.println(sub.get(0));
            sub.add(1,ip);
        }       
    }
```

In this example, the first element in the row is an IP address. I am trying to add the same exact IP address to the second element and push the rest of the data right. (There will be two of the same IP addresses next to each other). I plan on padding the IP address later but just want to get it added first.

I know that before i send my 2d ArrayList to "SpecialOperations" it is filled with valid data, because i can loop through it and it prints out the correct data, so i know its not an issue of empty data.

Edit: I have not used many other data types for lists other than Array Lists before. I've used hash maps and tree maps but not much. If this is not the right approach could you explain how i could use a different one?

Edit2: The question auto linked where it says mine is already answered doesnt answer mine. I know how to add to the middle. I think there is something wrong with how i'm implememnting my 2d ArrayList.

Comment: Adding in the middle makes me think LinkedList before ArrayList.

Comment: If you need a sorted list why not use a set, like TreeSet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert an object in an ArrayList at a specific position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074402/how-to-insert-an-object-in-an-arraylist-at-a-specific-position)

Comment: @duffymo I thought that the "Add" function for arraylists push the data over for me. I've never used LinkedLists in Java. Can you explain why that is a better option? (Or TreeSets for that matter).

Comment: @TritonMan I'm just more familiar with ArrayLists. My code i wrote should work right?Its only 3 lines of code and ArrayLists are pretty dynamic. Why would a TreeSet be better?

Comment: Btw: Type declarations should use the interface (List), not the implementation (ArrayList).

Comment: Ok. You have a bunch of questions loaded up. One thing at a time.

The reason duffymo wants you to consider using LinkedLists instead of arraylists is because of time complexity. Yes, arrayLists does push it over for you. But because it's in an array, it needs to shift every single element in behind it over.

For example, say you need to cut in front of a line. To do that, the person currently there and everyone behind him/her needs to move backwards one space. While this is ok with a small line, it gets out of hand when the line is say 100 people long..

Comment: A linkedlist is similar to an arraylist except the space for the line is arbitrary. This means you can stick a person anywhere in the 'line' without knowing there the line actually is. Each person only knows who's in front and who is in the back.

Comment: @TimZ. Okay that makes sense. So you're saying i should make an ArrayList of Linked Lists instead?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to design it to do. You should be interested in an ArrayList if you are going to call on it multiple times and where index is useful. Back to the people example. Are you going to call each person multiple times and you know what number associates to what person? Or is it a line for a movie? Once you deal with them, you never have to see them again.


Basically if you can utilize the indexes an arraylist gives you, use an arraylist. Otherwise use a linkedlist.

Comment: @TimZ. In this particular example, i plan to (On every row of data) add the 2nd IP address. And i will also change the format of two columns of data to make them SQL ready. So every ArrayList will add 1 cell and format 2 other cells. I have already successfully done this, but i wanted to convert to a 2D arraylist to optimize speeds. I think an ArrayList would be fine for my purposes but that just takes us back to my original question.

Comment: @TimZ. Okay i got it to successfully add now. Is playign around with Linked Lists worth it when the data sets are 30 columns wide? Thanks for you help.

Comment: Depends on how you access the data in the lists... A addLast/getLast method call is the same cost on an arraylist as a linked list. Add in front is cheaper in linkedlist than arraylist as well as adding in the middle. The only time arraylist is better than a linked list is when you need to jump in the middle of a list and you already know the index you need. Or when you need to sort the list. 



But if you're inserting to the front of a size 30 arrayList. yes you should consider using linkedlists.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add%28int,%20E%29) method of LinkedList:

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. Shifts the element currently at that position

I think this is exactly what you need.

One more thing:

```
<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>;
```

is a bit strange. Must be

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

Comment: Also, I am pretty sure you have the instantiate the inner arraylist as well. Otherwise it will be null.

Comment: @TimZ. When i fill the data i instantiate it there.

Comment: It should be `List<List<String>> data = new ArrayList<List<String>>();`

Comment: David Conrad, yes, I agree. The best practices advises to do it like this if don't need any special Collection Class methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. For any List implementation in Java, method `add(int index, E element)` will insert the element E to be at the index `index`, and shift everything to the right. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list (optional operation). Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices)

As mentioned in the comments above, you should try to keep your data type declaration as abstract as possible. Replace declaration of ArrayList to List in the declaration (see below)
It depends on the nature of your program that you choose the appropriate implementation of the abstract type `List<E>`. Java has 3 notable implementations: ArrayList, LinkedList (actually this is doubly linked list) and Stack.

I tested the below code at http://www.compileonline.com. "insert" element was inserted at the first place of the first inner arraylist.

```
public class Test {

    public static final List<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        data.add(new ArrayList<String>());
        data.get(0).add("1");
        data.get(0).add("2");
        data.get(0).add("3");
        SpecialOperations(data);

        for (String x : data.get(0)) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }

    static void SpecialOperations(List<ArrayList<String>> dat) {
        for(ArrayList<String> sub: dat){
            String ip = "ins";
            sub.add(1,ip);
        }       
    }
}
```