# how to add the previous element to the current index of a new arraylist

Tags: java

I need some help trying to figure out how would i add the current element from the old list to the current element in the new list

```
public List<Book> filterBooks(List<Book> readingList, String author)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < readingList.size();i ++)
    {
        List<Book> myList = new ArrayList<Book>();

        if (readingList.get(i).getAuthor().equals(author))
        {
            //how would i add the current element from the old list to the current element in the new list
         }
        readingList = myList;
    }
            return readingList;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074402/how-to-insert-an-object-in-an-arraylist-at-a-specific-position

Comment: `myList.add(readingList.get(i);`? And of course you will have to remove the  line `readingList = myList` and return myList instead.

Comment: **Never by index iteration with `List`**. If I pass a `LinkedList`, for example, to your method performance will drop to `O(n^2)`. Always use a `foreach` loop or an `Iterator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should move the creation of your list outside of the for loop as you don't want to create a new list each time the loop iterates. Assuming I understand the question you're asking, this should work:

```
public List<Book> filterBooks(List<Book> readingList, String author) {
    List<Book> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < readingList.size(); i++) {
        if (readingList.get(i).getAuthor().equals(author)) {
            myList.add(readingList.get(i));
        }
    }
    return myList;
}
```

Now, as @BoristheSpider has pointed out, it's not a good idea to use an index based loop while iterating over a list. Instead, you should use a foreach loop

```
public List<Book> filterBooks(List<Book> readingList, String author) {
    List<Book> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Book book : readingList) {
        if(book.getAuthor().equals(author)) {
            myList.add(book);
        }
    }
    return myList;
}
```

Comment: I had assumed that if OP doesn't know how to add an element to a list that explaining why it's better to use a foreach loop or iterator would be outside of my responsibilities.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Right, because in beginning level courses (which I'm taking the liberty of assuming OP is in) would accept an answer that uses topics that have yet to be covered. Like I said I took a liberty in assuming that so I may be wrong, but given the fact that OP had an indexed loop to begin with I thought I would give them the answer that they were close to

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to create the `myList` object inside of your loop. if you do then it will fall out of scope when the loop ends.

I recommend using the 'enhanced for loop' aka the 'for:each loop' as shown below.

You can add the element to the list quite simply with the line `myList.add(currentBook);`.

```
public List<Book> filterBooks(List<Book> readingList, String author)
{
    List<Book> myList = new ArrayList<Book>();

    for(Book currentBook : readingList)
    {
        if (currentBook.getAuthor().equals(author))
        {
            myList.add(currentBook);
        }
    }

    return myList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList

public List<Book> filterBooks(List<Book> readingList, String author) {
    return readingList.stream()
        .filter(book -> book.getAuthor().equals(author))
        .collect(toList());
}
```

In Java < 8

```
public List<Book> filterBooks(List<Book> readingList, String author) {
    List<Book> myList = new ArrayList<Book>();
    for(Book book : readingList) {        
        if (book.getAuthor().equals(author)) {
            myList.add(book);
        }
    }
    return myList;
}
```

Note that you should:

- declare the `List` *outside* of the loop;
- `return` the new `List`; and
- use a `foreach` loop